Horizontal Alignment Spacing in Cases Environment
I want to typeset some piecewise equations in MathJax and align the inequality symbols in the piecewise conditions. Using the cases environment and adding more ampersands does somewhat align the parts I want, but also adds extra horizontal space that I don't want. I can achieve the effect I want by adding whitespace characters, but that requires fiddling with the exact number and type of whitespace characters for every single line with different lengths and is also dependent on the renderer being used. Is there a more elegant and automatic way that works independent of the renderer?
Here's a simple example without alignment:

d_0(t) := d_{max} × \begin{cases}
0 & : −∞ ≤ t < T \\
1 & : T ≤ t < ∞
\end{cases}

Here's what I get from adding ampersands to align the less-than-or-equal signs (note the extra space between the left value and the LToE signs):

d_0(t) := d_{max} × \begin{cases}
0 & : −∞ & ≤ t < T \\
1 & : T & ≤ t < ∞
\end{cases}

And here's what I want to achieve visually, which I hacked up by adding several whitespace characters:

d_0(t) := d_{max} × \begin{cases}
0 & : −∞ ≤ t < T \\
1 & : \;\;\;\: T ≤ t < ∞
\end{cases}


I'd try setting the cases portion this way (requires mathtools): \begin{cases} 0 : −∞ & ≤ t < T \\ 1 : \phantom{$−∞$}\mathllap{T} & ≤ t < ∞ \end{cases}  (Not tested.)

The difference is in the position of the &s and the use of \phantom and \mathllap to position the T where you want it.  (But I could have made a typo.  Sadly, I'm not in a position to test this right now.)

@barbarabeeton It looks like MathJax doesn't support mathtools, so I can't use \mathllap.

Oh -- I missed the MathJax connection.  (Actually, MathJax is off topic here, but I think the posted answer should work, modulo the variant you mention in a comment.

If you replace \mathllap{T} by \llap{$T$} mathtools isn't needed.

It seems that you need three align points:

before the two values
before the colons
before the \leq signs

So you have to use 5 &s in the code. (For the reason, see the amsmath manual).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
d_0(t) := d_{\max} \times \left\{
  \begin{alignedat}{3}
    & 0    & & : \, & -\infty & \leq t < T \\
    & f(t) & & :    &       T & \leq t < \infty
  \end{alignedat}
\right.
\]
\end{document}



This works if the piecewise values are the same width, as is the case with the zero and one in my simplified examples, but when they aren't the same width it breaks down a bit: the left inequality-bound becomes left-aligned instead of right-aligned and the spacing loses alignment. Do you know how to fix that?

No. The left inequality-bound will always be right-aligned.

What do you mean by "the spacing loses alignment"?

I added a picture of what I get with your answer to the end of my question. The colons aren't aligned and the left bound is left-aligned.

@Lawton See the updated version.

It works now! Thank you.

You can use \newcases from mathtools:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcases{coloncases}% name
  {\quad}% separation
  {$\m@th\displaystyle##$\hfil}% left part
  {$\m@th:$\ \hfil$\m@th\displaystyle##$}%
  {\lbrace}% left delimiter
  {.}% right delimiter
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
d_0(t)=
d_{\mathrm{max}}\times
\begin{coloncases}
0    & -\infty\le t<T \\
f(t) & T\le t\le\infty
\end{coloncases}
\]

\end{document}


